# Show function after x amount of taps - but not the very first tap

Tags: java, android

I have a function, whereby the bear turns around after 20 taps;

That method is `turnAround`

It works, however the very first time I press it, it activates it straightaway, and then it works every 20 taps... Is there a way to just stop that very first tap from activating, and then continuing the count as normal?

```
public void onClick(View v){


                int nb_shown_lobby = sharedpreferences.getInt("nShownLobby", 0);
                if ((nb_shown_lobby % 20) == 0) {
                    turnAround();
                }

                nb_shown_lobby += 1;
                editor.putInt("nShownLobby", nb_shown_lobby);
                editor.commit();


                int random = (int) (Math.random() * manyDifferentStrings.length);
                if (random == oldVaue) {
                    random = (int) (Math.random() * manyDifferentStrings.length);
                }
                changingText.setText(manyDifferentStrings[random]);
                oldVaue = random;

                try {
                mySound.start();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
            /* Optional */ // mySound.start();

            }

            }
```

It works every 20 taps, which is fine, but it also activates straight away instead of waiting 20 taps.

Comment: `&& nb_shown_lobby != 0`

Comment: Where am I placing that @FedericoklezCulloca ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0%20 = 0
First time nb_shown_lobby  will be 0
You can change add this here

```
  if ((nb_shown_lobby  != 0)&&(nb_shown_lobby % 20) == 0)
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense - this works perfectly thank you.